# Restart supervisor after github workflow build

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions

I have a repo with GitHub action integrated. Once code is merged into the X branch it is deploying the latest changes on the X server where Supervisor is running.

My aim is to reload the supervisor once deployed new changes.

I tried to create a bash file and execute it from the workflow but the user is a runner.

Is there any way to achieve this?